# Omit schema in the DERBY Query

Tags: java, database, schema, datasource, derby

I have created a database named 'movie_db', set default schema to APP.
Then created a sample table named 'USERS'.

My connection to DB is as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/movie_db"/>        
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
```

Now I want to write some tests and try to execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS;
```

What I get:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist.
```

When I specify exactly the schema I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM APP.USERS
```

everything works fine.

How can I omit schema name in my query?

**UPDATE:**
Like Bryan said, I've created a user with the name of my default schema and authorize with this login. This is the most simple way to omit schema name in the query. But still if I want to use multiple schemas the only way is to set schema explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are basically two ways to control the default schema name:

1. Issue the SET SCHEMA statement after you have connected to the database.
2. Login as the user with the same name as the schema you wish to use.

If you haven't issued a SET SCHEMA statement, then Derby will use your username as the schema name.

So if you login as user "APP", and don't issue a SET SCHEMA statement, then your schema name will be APP.

Comment: Can I explicitly set schema in my bean? I've tried by setting property and adding key-value pair in the url, but that didn't work for me. And if it's not possible where exactly is the best way to set default schema? Inside each method for accessing DB of the DAO class?

Comment: SET SCHEMA is an SQL statement; you need to send that statement to the database using the JDBC API. It sounds like your real question involves how to get such SQL statements issued by your Object/Relational library, which isn't really a Derby issue, but an O/R Library issue.

Comment: No, I understand that set schema is an sql statement :) First of all, now I'm not using orm, but that is not a question of mine. I actually don't understand why I can't set default schema for the pool of my connections inside the datasource block in the app-context. Id on't want to hardcode my schema.

Comment: I solved the same problem, but with specific WAS alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032112/why-derby-does-not-use-property-currentshema-from-my-was-datasource/19089341#19089341  Don't know if you can do the same in your environment.

Comment: Official documentation for the second claim is [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefjdbc34565.html).