# Cannot access tables from ij. Not found while they exist

Tags: hibernate, derby

When running show tables; command in ij I get the following output(some rows omitted for clarity):

```
ij> show tables;
TABLE_SCHEM         |TABLE_NAME                    |REMARKS             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS                 |SYSALIASES                    |                    
....
BLOGDBADMIN         |BLOG_ENTRIES                  |                    
BLOGDBADMIN         |USERS                         |                    

22 rows selected
```

When running the following command I expected something else to happen but not this:

```
ij> SELECT * from USERS;
ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist.
```

In ij connection is established using blogDBAdmin account which is the owner of the database. The tables were created using hibernate, and as far as I can tell hibernate is having no problems accessing them. The persistence.xml used is the [following](http://pastebin.com/fph0LwMt)

Comment: Are any rows returned from "select * from blogdbadmin.users"? Is it a case sensitivity issue, where BLOGDBADMIN != blogDBAdmin?

Comment: Thank you "select * from blogdbadmin.users" solves the issue, though I don't understand why hasn't it worked earlier.

Everything is case insensitive in my experience

Comment: Since explicitly specifying the schema name worked, the issue is that you aren't getting the default schema that you expected to get. You might find some useful ideas in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735068/omit-schema-in-the-derby-query