# "Schema name-of-schema does not exist" with Java Derby

Tags: java, derby, javadb

Im currently making a program with Java which needs to access a Derby database. However, when I try to run it I get the error "Schema RCVT does not exist".
And, as I coded it, the program ends.
Here´s my code:

```
public ResultSetTableModel(String mController,
                           String URL,
                           String USERNAME,
                           String PASSWORD,
                           String mQuery) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName(mController);
    mConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    mStatement = mConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    mConnected = true;
    setConsult(mQuery);
}
```

Here are the parameters I send to this method:

```
private static final String CONTROLLER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:derby:GOT";
private static final String USERNAME = "rcvt";
private static final String PASSWORD = "rcvt";
private static final String PREDETERMINED_CONSULT = "SELECT * FROM Person";
```

And this is the SQL Script I execute from ij> inside the project:

```
DROP TABLE Person;
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ,
    age int NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    house VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    allegiance VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    continent VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    region VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Person (age, name, house, allegiance, alias, continent, region, title, active) VALUES (43, 'Cersei', 'Lannister', 'Lannister', 'The Lioness', 'Westeros', 'The Crownlands', 'Queen Of The Andals And The First Men', TRUE);
```

I have been looking a while for this error and I can't find the solution anywhere.

This is the exception I get:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=50596:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Vidriales Trujillo R\IdeaProjects\AccesoDB\out\production\AccesoDB;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derby.war;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbynet.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyrun.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_cs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_es.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_fr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_hu.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_it.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_pl.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_de_DE.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_ja_JP.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_ko_KR.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyLocale_zh_TW.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\db\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar" Runner
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'RCVT' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at ResultSetTableModel.setConsult(ResultSetTableModel.java:88)
    at ResultSetTableModel.<init>(ResultSetTableModel.java:28)
    at ConsultPersons.<init>(ConsultPersons.java:41)
    at GUI.<init>(GUI.java:9)
    at Runner$1.run(Runner.java:10)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'RCVT' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.StatementUtil.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.TableName.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConsultPersons.<init>(ConsultPersons.java:63)
    at GUI.<init>(GUI.java:9)
    at Runner$1.run(Runner.java:10)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

When it reaches this line:

```
mTableModel = new ResultSetTableModel(CONTROLLER, URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PREDETERMINED_CONSULT);
```

Which calls this method:

```
public void setConsult(String mConsult) throws SQLException,
            IllegalStateException {

        if (!mConnected) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Theres no DB connection");
        }
        mAllResults = mStatement.executeQuery(mConsult);
        mMetaData = mAllResults.getMetaData();
        mAllResults.last();
        mNumberOfRows = mAllResults.getRow();
        fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Include the **exact** exception that you got, with its stack trace, and specify the **exact** line of code that you have run when you get that message.

Comment: @BryanPendleton just included

Comment: It's not obvious to me why you're getting that exception. It might be worth dumping the value of 'mConsult' in the setConsult() method: is it really just "SELECT * FROM Person"? Since you're logging on as user 'rcvt', you should have the 'rcvt' schema as the current schema automatically. Perhaps when you opened up your "ij" session, you didn't log in as user 'rcvt'; instead you logged in as user 'app'? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735068/omit-schema-in-the-derby-query

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you. <https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954651/6295238>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in your SQL script. From official [FAQ](https://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#schema_exist):

> So you will see the schema not exists error if your application tries to access the current schema before any objects have been created in it. Possibilities are you try to perform a DROP TABLE before creating it, ...

This is your case. As you mentioned, you're creating schema from the IDE executing the script, so first time it will not work because table `Person` doesn't exists as well as corresponding schema.

To unstuck from that, explicitly create the schema in your script, or at least for the first run comment drop table command.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have been using Apache Hive with Derby, there is a configuration in `hive-site.xml` .