# Spring boot Embedded Derby not working in the latest version.

Tags: spring, spring-boot, derby

I have used Embedded derby earlier in my spring boot projects. But now when i created the project through Spring Initializr with the derby dependency. I get the below error :
**Schema 'SA' does not exist**
followed by **org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement**

When i tried running the earlier project that i had created, the Derby is working just fine.
PFB the console for the earlier project :

> 2018-03-18 15:34:44.346  INFO 16560 --- [  restartedMain]
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode
>   provider name : javassist 2018-03-18 15:34:44.391  INFO 16560 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001:
>   Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2018-03-18 15:34:44.490 
>   **INFO 16560 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>   : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
>   2018-03-18 15:34:44.497  WARN 16560 --- [  restartedMain]
>   org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect       : HHH000430: The DerbyDialect
>   dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects
>   ** instead 2018-03-18 15:34:45.094  INFO 16560 --- [  restartedMain]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl
>   schema export 2018-03-18 15:34:45.099 ERROR 16560 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389:
>   Unsuccessful: drop table book 2018-03-18 15:34:45.099 ERROR 16560 ---
>   [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Schema
>   'SA' does not exist 2018-03-18 15:34:45.129  WARN 16560 --- [ 
>   restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning
>   Code: 10000, SQLState: 01J01 2018-03-18 15:34:45.129  WARN 16560 --- [
>   restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database
>   'memory:testdb' not created, connection made to existing database
>   instead. 2018-03-18 15:34:45.129  INFO 16560 --- [  restartedMain]
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export
>   complete 2018-03-18 15:34:45.152  INFO 16560 --- [  restartedMain]
>   j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

The Console Log for my current spring boot with embedded derby :

> 2018-03-18 15:42:23.234  INFO 11312 --- [           main] 
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
>   2018-03-18 15:42:23.237  WARN 11312 --- [           main]
>   **com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with
>   driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found,
>   trying direct instantiation. 2018-03-18 15:42:23.844  INFO 11312 --- [
>   ** main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver
>   does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not
>   implemented: No details.) 2018-03-18 15:42:23.847  INFO 11312 --- [
>   main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
>   completed. 2018-03-18 15:42:23.937  INFO 11312 --- [           main]
>   j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2018-03-18
>   15:42:23.969  INFO 11312 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
>   PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: default   ...] 2018-03-18 15:42:24.136 
>   INFO 11312 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
>   : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.14.Final} 2018-03-18 15:42:24.138 
>   INFO 11312 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2018-03-18 15:42:24.199 
>   INFO 11312 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
>   Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2018-03-18 15:42:24.380  INFO 11312
>   --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
>   2018-03-18 15:42:25.572  WARN 11312 --- [           main]
>   o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget
>   encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC
>   Statement
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error
>   executing DDL via JDBC Statement  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
>   [hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]

The difference i can find between the two is that in the current log(abv log) it says that the 
**com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with
 driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found,
trying direct instantiation.**

Let me know if we need to configure something apart from the below dependency for enabling this derby. Note- I dint do anything apart from maven dependency in the previous project.

Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>            
 <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
 <scope>runtime</scope>         
 </dependency>
```

Comment: looks like the schema "SA" from persistence.xml doesn't exists the db

Answer (score 10):

Please configure you JPA Configuration as per your requirement. I've configured as below. You need to add below configuration in application.properties file.

```
# PROFILES
spring.profiles.active=dev
# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```sh
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

to your ***`application.properties`***
it is by default create-drop.

Answer (score 0):

The default driver used by derby is `org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver`, but springboot and other framework choice `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`.
It causes the driver to be unable to find the driver when using the datasource for the first time.

About `Schema 'SA' does not exist`. 
I think that you use the other tool connect the derby, such as **ij**. And the jdbc url they use is the same. It looks like the same database connected, but it's not actually.
This is the key to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Added this in appplication.properties and worked

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added below property in application.properties, it worked!

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```